# enclose columns in quotes using hiveql

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

```
Hive Version 0.13
```

I am having a column in hive which needs to be enclosed in double quotes

I am trying with the below query but the output is returned as NULL

```
select "\""+notes_detail+"\"" from  service_request_notes.TSS_INCIDENT_NOTES_F_SAMPLE limit 1;
```

where as the output should be this

```
select notes_detail from  service_request_notes.TSS_INCIDENT_NOTES_F_SAMPLE limit 1;
```

Job 0: Map: 106   Cumulative CPU: 151.24 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 minutes 31 seconds 240 msec
OK
notes_detail
From: scottw@acespower.com

Comment: The way your text is formatted, it's hard to understand what you want vs. what you get. Anyway, remember that in Hive (like in standard SQL) the string literals use *simple quotes* and the concatenation operator is *not* **+** -- this is not bloody SQL Server!!!

Comment: `select concat('"', whatever, '"') from whatever`